# Break lines in custom list environment

Tags: lists

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\itemColor}[1]{\item[\llap{\textcolor{blue}{#1}\hspace*{.75mm}}]}

\newcommand{\listConfig}{                                                                     
  \setlength{\topsep}{-10pt} % amount of extra vertical space at top of list                                            
    \setlength{\partopsep}{\baselineskip} % extra length at top if environment is preceded by a blank line (it should be a rubber length)                                          
    \setlength{\parsep}{\baselineskip} % amount of vertical space between paragraphs within an item                     
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-\baselineskip} % amount of extra vertical space between items                                 
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2cm} % horizontal distance between the left margins of the environment and the list; must be nonnegative                               
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm} % horizontal distance betwen the right margins of the enviroment and the list; must be nonnegative                       
    \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt} % indentation of first line of an item; can be negative                                
    \setlength{\labelsep}{2mm} % separation between end of the box containing the label and the text of the first line of an item                                                
} 

\newenvironment{descr}{%           
  \vspace{.1in}                
  \begin{list}{}{%             
    \listConfig              
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}                   
  }                         
}{\end{list}\vspace{.1in}} 

\begin{document}

This is a descriptive environment:

    \begin{descr}
        \itemColor{title 1}\lipsum[1]
        \itemColor{long long long long long long long title}\lipsum[1]
        \itemColor{test}\lipsum[1]
    \end{descr}
\end{document}
```

Which produce this:

[image]

As you can see, it do not look nice with a long title. However, I did not think a way to break lines, manually or automatically, in my `itemColor` command. Any idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to customize `\makelabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% \newcommand{\itemColor}[1]{\item[\llap{\textcolor{blue}{#1}\hspace*{.75mm}}]}

\newcommand{\listConfig}{%
  % amount of extra vertical space at top of list:
  \setlength{\topsep}{-10pt}%
  % extra length at top if environment is preceded by a blank line (it
  % should be a rubber length):
  \setlength{\partopsep}{\baselineskip}%
  % amount of vertical space between paragraphs within an item:
  \setlength{\parsep}{\baselineskip}%
  % amount of extra vertical space between items
  \setlength{\itemsep}{-\baselineskip}%
  % horizontal distance between the left margins of the environment
  % and the list; must be nonnegative:
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{2cm}%
  % horizontal distance betwen the right margins of the enviroment and
  % the list; must be nonnegative:
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}%
  % indentation of first line of an item; can be negative:
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
  % separation between end of the box containing the label and the
  % text of the first line of an item:
  \setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}%
}

\newenvironment{descr}{%
  \vspace{.1in}
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \listConfig
% doesn't all of this belong to \listConfig?
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}%
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{{\color{blue}\smash{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\labelwidth-.75mm\relax}
                               {\raggedleft\strut##1\strut}}\hfil}}%
    }%
}{\end{list}\vspace{.1in}}

\begin{document}

This is a descriptive environment:

    \begin{descr}
        \item[title 1]\lipsum[1]
        \item[long long long long long long long title]\lipsum[1]
        \item[test]\lipsum[1]
    \end{descr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package can do this. This package lets you customise list environments (such as `description`) using `<key>=<value>` pairs. The following key+value almost does what you want: (from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/))

> `style=multiline`: the label is placed in a parbox whose width is leftmargin, with several lines if necessary. Same as `style=standard,align=parleft,labelwidth=!`.

The only problem is that `align=parleft` causes the labels to be left aligned instead of right aligned. Unfortunately `enumitem` does not recognise `\parright`, but we can remedy this by also adding `\raggedleft` to the `\font=` key.

I think this code thus does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% <- for \lipsum
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

%% Note: this \leavevmode is necessary, see the addendum:
\begin{description}[align=parleft,labelwidth=!,
                    font=\raggedleft\normalfont\leavevmode\color{blue},
                    leftmargin=2cm]
\item[title 1] \lipsum[66] %% <- \lipsum[66] is short
\item[long long long long long long long title] \lipsum[66]
\item[test] \lipsum[66]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add other keys, like `topsep=<...>` or `itemsep=<...>` etc., to set the other parameters you've tweaked. See the `enumitem` documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for more information.

---

*Alternative: you could also define `parright` yourself by copying the definition of `parleft` and replacing `\raggedright` by `\raggedleft`, like this:*

```
\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedleft#1}}}
```

*If you then use `parright` instead of `parleft` you can leave out the `\raggedleft` from the `font=` key.*

---

If you plan to use this style more than once you can also change all `description` environments in one go by adding the following line to your preamble. You can of course add the other keys I've mentioned before.

```
\setlist[description]{align=parleft,labelwidth=!,font=\raggedleft\normalfont\leavevmode\color{blue},leftmargin=2cm}
```

If you want to use this style more often but don't want to redefine the default description environment, you can create your own environment using:

```
\newlist{mydescr}{description}{1} %% last argument is the maximum depth.
\setlist[mydescr]{align=parleft,labelwidth=!,font=\raggedleft\normalfont\leavevmode\color{blue},leftmargin=2cm}
```

### Addendum:

The `\leavevmode` in my `font=\raggedleft\normalfont\leavevmode\color{blue}` was necessary because it appears that `\color` can't be used at the start of a `\parbox` "for technical reasons". I had no idea why this is, so I've just asked [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435851/156366) about it, which has already been [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435852/156366).

Answer (score 3):

If you want line breaks in your long long title, I'd use a tabular instead of a list, but the result will probably not be very pretty if you break lines in such a narrow columns. I think I would go for a normal description environment where long title will continue in the first line of the text body.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}

\setlist{
    font=\normalfont\bfseries\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{description}
    \item[title 1] \lipsum[1]
    \item[long long long long long long long title] \lipsum[1]
    \item[test] \lipsum[1]
    \end{description}

    \begin{tabular}{>{\color{blue}\bfseries\raggedleft}p{.15\textwidth}>{\color{black}}p{.8\textwidth}}
        title 1 & \lipsum[1]\\
        long long long long long long long title & \lipsum[1]\\
    test & \lipsum[1]
    \end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]