# Using \color inside a \parbox causes vertical displacement

Tags: color, boxes, parbox

When modifying [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435834/156366) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435396/156366) I came across some odd behaviour.
If `\color{<color>}` is used at the start of a top-aligned `\parbox`, then the entire box is moved downwards, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
Word
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{word}} %% <- this is fine
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{\textcolor{blue}{word}}} %% <- this is fine
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{\color{blue}word}} %% <- ??
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{\hskip0pt\color{blue}word}} %% <- this is fine
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{\leavevmode\color{blue}word}} %% <- this is fine
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{$\displaystyle\int$}} %% <- this is fine
\framebox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{\color{blue}$\displaystyle\int$}} %% <- ??
\end{document}
```

[image]

*(The `\framebox`es are just there to show the locations/sizes of the `\parbox`es.)*

Can someone tell me why this happens (and how I can best avoid it)?

Comment: footnote on page 6 of `texdoc grfguide`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\color` is usually implemented via "whatsits", i.e. `\special` or `\pdfcolorstack` in case of pdfTeX. It becomes the top element at the start of the vertical box (`\parbox[t]`). The following paragraph starts below. Putting it after `\leavevmode` at the baseline of the starting paragraph is the right fix.

For debugging, a box can be inspected by `\showbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
  \showboxdepth=\maxdimen
  \showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
  \tracingonline=1
  \setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[t]{1cm}{\color{blue}word}}
  \showbox0
\end{document}
```

The console (with `\tracingonline=1`) and the `.log` file reports:

```
\hbox(0.0+6.94444)x28.45274
.\vbox(0.0+6.94444)x28.45274
..\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG}
..\glue(\parskip) 0.0
..\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x28.45274, glue set 7.03604fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 w
...\kern-0.27779
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\pdfcolorstack 0 pop

! OK.
l.8   \showbox0
```